# How is revoking a CA cert possible?

Tags: certificate-authority

From what I understand, the cert is created using a private key ONLY ONCE, and once it's issued to a website, it stays on that website's server. As a retrospective measure, how can a CA make this cert invalid again if it can't remove the cert from someone else's server, and it can't change the public/private keys which will make all other sites invalid as well?

Answer (score 1):

This is accomplished via a revocation list vis. RFC 5280.  The client can request a CRL (certificate Revocation List) from the CA (certificate Authority).  The CRL is signed and timestamped by the CA. The client can check against this list during the handshake (note that certain browsers have been lazy historically about checking this because of increased latency).  To avoid added latency OCSP stapling is an option which passes the CRL to the client by the server during the handshake.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_revocation_list

https://www.digicert.com/util/utility-test-ocsp-and-crl-access-from-a-server.htm

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280

Comment: And how is MiTM prevented while getting the CRL?

Comment: The CRL is signed by the CA.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged because the links could go stale. Can you pull the relevant information into your answer?

Comment: added the content contained in the links as requested by @MikeOunsworth